# Declare variable for just time

Tags: c#

I need to create a variable that contains time in the format hh:mm, how shall I do that?

```
DateTime currentTime = "00:00";
```

doesn't seem to do the trick. I need to add hours/minutes in a loop to that variable and keep the format "hh:mm". How is that done?

/M

Comment: You don't need to add hours/minutes in a loop. You also can format any DateTime structure as "hh:mm".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably use `TimeSpan` for that?

Comment: @molgan: Have you looked at the documentation? It's reasonably clear.

Comment: Semantically, TimeSpan doesn't make much sense. Since .NET doesn't have a dedicated Time class, I'd just use an integer representing the number of minutes since midnight (assuming you only need minute-level precision).

Comment: @molgan - MSDN page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Comment: @Porges: TimeSpan may make sense, or it may not - the question isn't clear about what he's trying to do.

Comment: `TimeSpan _Span = new TimeSpan(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);`

Then you are able to add new values just by `_Span.AddHours(int hours)` or `_Span.AddMinutes(int minutes)` and then read it via `string _NewSpan = _Span.TotalHours().ToString();` and so on.

See MSDN for further detail.

Answer (score 11):

You should distinguish between the quantity you're trying to keep track of, and the eventual string formatting. They're different things.

Are you trying to maintain a time of day (in which case using `DateTime` and ignoring the date part is probably best) or a duration of time (in which case `TimeSpan` is most appropriate)? Either way, pick your data type, use it in your loop, and then deal with formatting as and when you need to.

(Just as a heads-up, I'm part of a new project called [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time) which keeps all of these as different types; it's a port of the popular [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) project for Java. We're a very long way from releasing anything, but in a year's time I hope it would be the best answer for this question :)

Comment: "to maintain a time of day ... DateTime"
.NET DateTime.TimeOfDay is a TimeSpan.

Comment: @Guillaume: Yes, but but that gives the time since midnight. Suppose you want to keep adding 1 hour, 50 times. If you're tracking the time of day, the result should be 02:00. If you're tracking a duration, the result will be 50:00. Using DateTime, repeatedly adding hours and then finally taking the TimeOfDay will give you the first result; using a TimeSpan from the start will give you the second. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I see what you mean but if you do it this way, you may overflow. TimeSpan is more consistent and if you want the time in the day you can easily Mod 24H. Why would you store/work with a date when you are only interrested in time ?

Comment: @Guillaume: What sort of overflow are you afraid of? Overflowing the range of DateTime? Sounds unlikely to me. As for why you'd use a DateTime: if you're working with a *time of day* that relates to a time rather than a time duration, I think it makes more conceptual sense to stick with a time which represents that. Why would you store/work with a period when you're interseted in a time of day? Ideally of course, there should be a data type representing "time of day" rather than "period" or "duration" - which is where Noda Time comes in :)

Comment: You can overflow if you use the same DateTime incrementing again and again carrying only about time and not about date that can increase to MaxValue. DateTime represent a precise absolute instant in time, TimeSpan is a time interval. What molgan asked is how to represent a time hh:MM, not an absolute Date but something like an offset from midnight of any day which is way better to represent with a TimeSpan than with a DateTime where you ignore Date.

Comment: @Guillaume: Do you think a TimeSpan will never overflow, if you add enough stuff to it? I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this - .NET is basically lacking the relevant type, but a time of day is *never* 25:00, which a TimeSpan can represent - which is why I feel that using a DateTime may be more appropriate. Both will work.

Comment: DateTime will overflow because of Date, if TimeSpan overflow this will be more expected.
TimeOfDay is represented by Microsoft with a TimeSpan even if, when you add it time, it can be more than 24hours. But well, you go with a DateTime, me, the 9 upvoters and Microsoft go with a TimeSpan.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

Timespan is your best bet, or use DateTime.toString("hh:mm")

Comment: I would suggest "HH:mm" is more likely to be appropriate, to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following and ignore the date part

```
DateTime current;
DateTime.TryParse("13:00", out current);
```

To get just the time out use

```
current.ToString("hh:mm");
```

Comment: "hh:mm" will give a 12-hour time, i.e. it will be ambiguous between 1am and 1pm.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a normal datetime-variable with todays date, starting at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

A simple integer? `hours = number / 60; minutes = number % 60`